# GORM Postgres - driver: bad connection on parallel selects with transactions

Tags: postgresql, go, transactions, go-gorm

I'm encountering an issue where I get `driver: bad connection` when running multiple queries in parallel in a transaction. Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/avast/retry-go"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

var (
    db *gorm.DB
)

func NewGorm(databaseURL string) (*gorm.DB, error) {
    db, err := gorm.Open(
        postgres.New(
            postgres.Config{
                DSN:                  databaseURL,
                PreferSimpleProtocol: true, // disables implicit prepared statement usage
            },
        ),
        &gorm.Config{
            Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Silent),
        },
    )

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return db, nil
}

func Init() {
    databaseURL := os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL")

    logrus.WithField("databaseURL", databaseURL).Info("Database connection")

    if err := retry.Do(
        func() error {
            var connectionErr error

            db, connectionErr = NewGorm(databaseURL)

            if connectionErr != nil {
                logrus.Warning("retrying database")

                return connectionErr
            }

            return nil
        },
    ); err != nil {
        logrus.WithError(err).Panic("database")
    }

    if debug, err := strconv.ParseBool(os.Getenv("DEBUG")); debug && err == nil {
        db = db.Debug()
    } else {
        logrus.Warning(err)
    }
}

func select_from_db(tx *gorm.DB) {
    tx.Table("table_name").Find(&[]models.A{})
    tx.Table("table_name").Find(&[]models.A{})
    tx.Table("table_name").Find(&[]models.A{})
    tx.Table("table_name").Find(&[]models.A{})
}

func main() {
    logrus.SetLevel(logrus.TraceLevel)
    Init()
    tx := db.Begin()
    go select_from_db(tx)
    go select_from_db(tx)
    go select_from_db(tx)
    go select_from_db(tx)
    go select_from_db(tx)
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    tx.Commit()
}
```

When running this code as is, often I'll get:

```
[0.222ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM "table_name"

2023/06/15 13:14:51 main.go:72 driver: bad connection
```

but, when commenting `tx := db.Begin()` and `tx.Commit()`, this does not reproduce.
I don't understand why this is happening and how I can avoid it. Any insight will be great.
Thank you

Comment: Postgres does not support concurrent queries over a single connection (and a transaction is bound to a connection, obviously).

Comment: Thanks @Peter. Can you explain a bit more? When I don't use a transaction, how come it works?

Comment: When you don't use a transaction, the database driver uses multiple connections, one per query.

Comment: Thank you. Will accept as an answer if you want to post it